# Javascript library for rendering HTML form elements

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know of a JavaScript library for rendering form elements? For example for a select element, I'd like to be able supply classes, an id and an array of items for rendering into an html select element.

Comment: I don't know of any, but I'd think it would be easy enough to create with a fair knowledge of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want a library that really *draws* things itself, but reading between the lines I think you just want to build HTML elements yourself. In that case, you could use jQuery. It can be as easy as:

```
$("<select>")
  .append(
    $("<option>").text("first"),
    $("<option>").text("second"),
    $("<option>").text("third")
  )
  .addClass("class1 class2")
  .attr("id", "someid")
  .appendTo("body");
```

Comment: Sounds promising. Can jQuery be used to create DOM elements from scratch?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, it offers a straight-forward way to do so - just pass any HTML string to the jQuery function (`$`), and it will return an object containing the elements the HTML string specified. You can then manipulate the elements as you wish using all those functions available in jQuery.

Comment: OK, thanks. I wasn't previously aware of that DOM element construction syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I started working on a system that build forms based on JSON data automatically. You're welcome to [go steal the code](http://preview.moveable.com/JM/jameslab/JSONForm/).

P.S. it was a loooong time ago.

Comment: broken link tut

Answer (score 1):

You can try javascript UI libraries like Jquery Tools, Jquery UI.

- Jquery Tools -> http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/index.html (see the Form Tools section).
- Jquery UI -> http://jqueryui.com/demos/